# How to obtain a OutputStream on Soundcloud account to upload my content using Outstream.write() ??

Tags: java, inputstream, soundcloud, outputstream

Here is the Detailed objective of mine

1. Get a Input Stream of audio from its publicly available link
2. Get a output stream of soundcloud to which i can write after reading from input stream using something like this

   ```
   InputStream input = new URL("http://mywebsite.com/my.mp3').openStream();
   bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
   while (bytesRead != -1) {

       outputStreamOfSoundcloud.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
   }
   ```

The Java Wrapper for soundcloud needs the file access to the audio to upload (discussed here [How to upload audio in soundcloud via my app and i want to send that id also to my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588444/how-to-upload-audio-in-soundcloud-via-my-app-and-i-want-to-send-that-id-also-to) ) ..
But How to do a Outstream/buffer write to Soundcloud to upload my content ??

Comment: There may be some sort of "virtual memory file" api in java, ie. a file which is only backed by an in-memory byte array and does not exist on disk. Then you could write your audio data into that byte array and upload your virtual file. Never tried this though.